# Assign value to objects through json in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

i'm new to objective c and just trying to add value to existing object.

Please have a look at my code below.

It's working fine when i create objects like this

```
 ToAddiTem *item1 = [[ToAddiTem alloc] init];
 item1.itemName = @"Some value";
 [self.toDoItems addObject:item1];

 ToAddiTem *item2 = [[ToAddiTem alloc] init];
 item2.itemName = @"Some value";
 [self.toDoItems addObject:item2];

 ToAddiTem *item3 = [[ToAddiTem alloc] init];
 item3.itemName = @"Some value";
 [self.toDoItems addObject:item3];
```

But when i'm trying to do this dynamically with json webservices, it's not working at all.

Please have a look below.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://acumen- locdef.elasticbeanstalk.com/service/countries"];


NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];


[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response,
                                           NSData *data, NSError *connectionError)
 {
     if (data.length > 0 && connectionError == nil)
     {
         NSMutableArray *greeting = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                             options:0
                                                               error:NULL];

         for (NSDictionary *countryList in greeting) {

            ToAddiTem *item1 = [[ToAddiTem alloc] init];
            item1.itemName = countryList[@"name"];
            [self.toDoItems addObject:item1];

         }


     }
 }];
```

Many thanks for your help!!

Comment: what you get when you print countryList[@"name"] at NSlog

Comment: Hi Jincy, when i use NSlog with the countryList[@"name"] inside for loop it's showing all the results. But i can't use this outside from the loop.

Answer (score 0):

you may need to initialise, toDoItems Array

```
self.toDoItems = [NSMutableArray array];
```

and then

```
for (NSDictionary *countryList in greeting) {

        ToAddiTem *item1 = [[ToAddiTem alloc] init];
        item1.itemName = countryList[@"name"];
        [self.toDoItems addObject:item1];

     }
```

Comment: Hey, i have already added this under interface. 
@property NSMutableArray *toDoItems;

Answer (score 0):

You might be getting a deserialization error.

```
 NSError *err;
 NSMutableArray *greeting = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                         options:0
                                                           error:NULL];

 if (err)
 {
     NSLog(@"Error deserializing JSON: %@", [err localizedDescription]);
 }
 else
 {
     for (NSDictionary *countryList in greeting) {

        ToAddiTem *item1 = [[ToAddiTem alloc] init];
        item1.itemName = countryList[@"name"];
        [self.toDoItems addObject:item1];

     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and found out that this is due to the fact that you are getting your data asynchronously. So your code does not wait until the data is there, it just continues.

If you switch it to a synchronous call, it will work:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://acumen-locdef.elasticbeanstalk.com/service/countries"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSError *error = nil;
NSHTTPURLResponse *responseCode = nil;
NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&responseCode error:&error];
NSMutableArray *greeting = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:NULL];

for (NSDictionary *countryList in greeting) {
    ToAddiTem *item1 = [[ToAddiTem alloc] init];
    item1.itemName = countryList[@"name"];
    [self.toDoItems addObject:item1];
}
```